# Jboss & EJB3 deploy Error for

Tags: jboss, ejb-3.0

I am a newer for EJB3 dev.
When I write a EJB3 mdb and I want to deploy it to my jboss (jboss-4.2.3.GA)
some error info is here:

> --- MBeans waiting for other MBeans --- ObjectName: jboss.j2ee:jar=HelloWorldEjb.jar,name=QueneMDB01,service=EJB3   State:
>   FAILED   Reason: org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentException: Required
>   config property RequiredConfigPropertyM
>   etaData@12c08c7[name=destination
>   descriptions=[DescriptionMetaData@1941dc9[language=zh]]] for messag
>   ingType 'javax.jms.MessageListener' not found in activation config
>   [ActivationConfigProperty(destina tionType=javax.jms.Queue),
>   ActivationConfigProperty(acknowledgeMode=Auto-acknowledge)]
>   ra=jboss.jca: service=RARDeployment,name='jms-ra.rar'
>
> --- MBEANS THAT ARE THE ROOT CAUSE OF THE PROBLEM --- ObjectName: jboss.j2ee:jar=HelloWorldEjb.jar,name=QueneMDB01,service=EJB3   State:
>   FAILED   Reason: org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentException: Required
>   config property RequiredConfigPropertyM
>   etaData@12c08c7[name=destination
>   descriptions=[DescriptionMetaData@1941dc9[language=zh]]] for messag
>   ingType 'javax.jms.MessageListener' not found in activation config
>   [ActivationConfigProperty(destina tionType=javax.jms.Queue),
>   ActivationConfigProperty(acknowledgeMode=Auto-acknowledge)]
>   ra=jboss.jca: service=RARDeployment,name='jms-ra.rar'

and my mdb is :

```
@MessageDriven(activationConfig = {
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode", propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge"),
    @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue") })

public class QueneMDB01 implements MessageListener 
{
    public void onMessage(Message msg) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            TextMessage textMessage = (TextMessage) msg;
            System.out.println("MyQueneMDBBean is called "
                    + textMessage.getText() + " ");
        } catch (JMSException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From your error i'd say you forgot to add the destination name (queue name probably).

```
FAILED Reason: org.jboss.deployment.DeploymentException: Required config property RequiredConfigPropertyM etaData@12c08c7[name=destination descriptions=[DescriptionMetaData@1941dc9[language=zh]]
```

Example:
http://www.javaissues.com/2011/06/ejb3-message-driven-bean-hello-world.html

BTW, you've set up your queues/topics in JBoss right?

Hope this helps,
Dave